# How to get upload progress with Java SDK for Dropbox API v2?

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have searched the Dropbox documentation on its Developers page and on Stack Overflow, and I haven't found a way to get the upload progress of a file in the Java SDK for API v2. I don't have idea how to get the upload progress. Could someone help me with this?

I tried with `ProgresMonitorInputStream`, but it only tells me the progress of reading the file, it does not indicate the upload progress to the Dropbox server.

```
DbxRequestConfig config = DbxRequestConfig.newBuilder("My App/1.0.0").build();
DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN);

    FileMetadata metadata;

    try {
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filepath)) {

            InputStream progressMonitorInputStream = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(null, "Uploading...", in);

            metadata = client.files()
                    .uploadBuilder("/test.exe")
                    .withMode(WriteMode.OVERWRITE)
                    .uploadAndFinish(progressMonitorInputStream);
        }

    } catch (DbxException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        return;
    }
```

I want the upload progress to show it in a JProgressBar.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/How-to-get-upload-progress-with-Java-SDK-v2/m-p/201573#M9508 ]

Comment: Have you found a solution on this :) ? I will be very glad to hear your news cause i need this also . I figured out how to get the progress of download but not for upload...

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS check main answer.

Comment: @CristiamMercado Gladddd so glad thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Greg K. from Dropbox team recently responded to this:

> The Dropbox API v2 Java SDK now offers progress listeners for uploads and downloads. This has been released in v3.0.9:
>
> https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/releases/tag/v3.0.9
>
> There's an example of using it with with the `uploadAndFinish` method (https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxUploader.html#uploadAndFinish-java.io.InputStream-long-com.dropbox.core.util.IOUtil.ProgressListener-) for an upload here:
>
> https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/upload-file/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/upload_file/Main.java#L50
>
> It works the same way with file downloads; the download method (https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v3.0.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxDownloader.html#download-java.io.OutputStream-com.dropbox.core.util.IOUtil.ProgressListener-) optionally takes a `ProgressListener` parameter the same way.

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/How-to-get-upload-progress-with-Java-SDK-v2/m-p/297837#M18078]